# Chrome gives me NX_DOMAIN when using Laravel Valet

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, valet

I was having this issue today where I could not use Chrome web browser to view my Laravel projects using valet domain.test domains.

I was getting this issue: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of digging I found that the problem was caused through a config in my Chrome security settings.

If you navigate to this tab in Chrome Settings < Security & Privacy Tab < Security Settings you need to either disable Secure DNS or change the DNS provider to your current provider which works in my case.

Hope this helps someone, thanks for reading.